# using regex in replaceAll to replace multiple char in one go

Tags: apex, regular-expressions

I have a phone number that i need to convert to a valid format to be send to a webservice validator. The phone number should be 10 char long and should contains only digits.

For instance, I should convert

```
 +567 231 34 34 to 5672313434
 (567)231-34-34 to 5672313434
```

before sending

I have the solution which does the replacement in apex :

```
   String t = '+571 567 65 77';
   String r = t.replaceAll('\\(','');
   r = r.replaceAll('\\)','');
   r = r.replaceAll('-','');
   r = r.replaceAll('\\+','');
   r = r.replaceAll('\\s','');
   system.debug('## final result is :' + r);
```

Can I obtain the result in a single line?

Comment: +567 231 34 34 is not the same phone number as 5672313434.  The first is a 8 digit number in chile (I have no idea if it's a valid 8 digit number), the second is a 10 digit number in whatever country you are currently in.  In most of Europe +567 231 34 34 using only digits would be 005672313434, in the US it would be 0115672313434.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this:

```
String r = t.replaceAll('[^0-9]','');
```

**Explanation:**

Instead of hunting for invalid characters and removing them explicitly you can specify remove all characters **other than numbers**.

- `^` for not a given char
- `[0-9]` for numbers ranging from 0 to 9
- `''` replace it with empty char (removes it from our string)

Answer (score 3):

You can use ReplaceAll method

try Like this

```
String t = '(567)231-34-34';
String r = t.replaceAll('[^\\d]','');
system.debug('## final result is :' + r);

String t1 = '+567 231 34 34';
String r1 = t1.replaceAll('[^\\d]','');
system.debug('## final result is :' + r1);
```

**Reference:**

- `^` - Negates character class.
- `\d` - any digit character same as `[0-9]`

**Debug logs**

> 13:27:40:044 USER_DEBUG [3]|DEBUG|## final result is :5672313434
>   13:27:40:044 USER_DEBUG [7]|DEBUG|## final result is :5672313434

---

Another option

```
String t = '(567)231-34-34';
String r = t.replaceAll('[-+()s]','');
system.debug('## final result is :' + r);

String t1 = '+567 231 34 34';
String r1 = t1.replaceAll('[-+()s]','');
system.debug('## final result is :' + r1);
```

**Reference:**

- `[ ]`    Demarcates a character class. To interpret literally, use a backslash.
- `[abc]` is a `character class` that means "any character from a,b or c" (a characer class may use ranges, eg `[a-d] = [abcd]`)

**Debug logs**

> 13:26:13:004 USER_DEBUG [3]|DEBUG|## final result is :5672313434 
>   13:26:13:004 USER_DEBUG [7]|DEBUG|## final result is :567 231 34 34